# How to prepare brochure using 72 dpi raster images for offset print?

Tags: print-production, rasterization

I'm new in design & printing profession.

Please give your valuable suggestions on preparing a brochure for printing in an off-set printing press.

1) The brochure will contain around 20 pictures and the most problematic issue is - I have to use 20 jpeg's (raster image) collected from different websites. Average pixel sizes 1200x1000 pixels and 72 dpi resolution.

2) The jpeg's are of different sizes (dimensions) but I have to place the jpeg's in an specific size ( height: 1.7 inch and width: 2 inch ) in my brochure. All images of the brochure will be same size.

There is no other way to get better images and I have to extract the best output from these available resources (jpeg's).

Please give your valuable suggestion on how should I proceed to get best possible printed brochure from off-set press by using Illustrator.

Comment: Please don't use all caps in your body, it can come across as (angry) shouting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have fallen foul of [The Myth of DPI/PPI](http://www.rideau-info.com/photos/mythdpi.html).  It's a typical beginners mistake.

The DPI/PPI is not the resolution of a digital image or a measure of its quality.  It's only a number set in the image file's metadata.

If you print an image 1200px wide at a size 1.7" wide, the effective print resolution is 1200/1.7 = 705 DPI

So, as you can see, that's more than enough detail to print these images at that size, no matter what the PPI setting in the image file is set to.

The good news is you don't have to do anything. There's nothing to fix!

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Billy. What you said is really true. I followed it and found good result in a test shot. Other people misguided me saying resolution issues. You just give a simple calculation to let me realize everything clearly. Thanks again for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Offset printing of images requires using a screening process -- the image must be broken into solid-color dots or lines. This is why the physical screens used before digital pre-press were called line screens and dot screens. The software does the screening now, but it's still part of the process, because printing presses can only print solid color dots -- there are no tints or shades. All tints and shades are made by tricking our eyes with very tiny solid color dots. Look up the four-color printing process some time -- it's fascinating technology and is STILL the way images are printed on offset printing presses.

The frequency or pitch of the screen (expressed in dpi or lpi) determines how fine the look of the printed image will be. Better paper can handle higher frequency/smaller pitch screens. Newsprint can handle only 85-100 lpi. Very high quality coated stock can handle 150 and higher screen frequencies.

Designers should always talk to their commercial printers about the screen frequency to be used. Then use the formula of about 1.5 times the screen frequency for the image requirement. For example, to print a 1-inch square image at 150 lpi screen, I need about 225 dpi, so the image must be 225x225 pixels (actual pixels, which in this case is also pixels per inch). If this image was going to be 5 inches wide, it would need to be 1125 x 1125 pixels approximately.

Some people swear you must have 2 times the pixels as the screen resolution, but that's just playing it extra safe in many cases. Adobe printing guides have always said that 1.5 is often just fine and 2 times can be too much, but 2 times became a kind of "rule" because it's easy to remember.

If the image has more pixels than needed, you waste disk space, make unnecessarily large file sizes, and risk having soft focus. Too few pixels and you get jagged lines and blocky looking images.